# Asp.Net Core Http failure response for http://localhost:5000/company/getCompanyById/3: 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

I'm new to C# and Asp.Net and I m getting a 404 error on getting or deleting a company by Id .The Api for getting all Companies works fine.

API for allCompanies : http://localhost:5000/company/getcompaniesTest(which works)

for GetById:  http://localhost:5000/company/getCompanyById/3 (not working)

Here is my Controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Bearer")]
[ApiController]

[Route("company")]

public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public CompanyController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this._mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getcompanies")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanies()
        => new JsonResult(await _mediator.Send(new GetCompanies.Query()));    

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [Route("getCompanyById")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyById([FromQuery] GetCompanyById.Query query)
        => new JsonResult(await _mediator.Send(query));

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    [Route("deleteCompany")]
     public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCompanyTest([FromQuery] DeleteCompany.Command command)
          => new JsonResult(await _mediator.Send(command));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Or** you use the route in protocol decorator [Http(your route)], **Or** in Route decorator [Route(your route)].

**Not in both**! Try this:

```
[HttpGet("getCompanyById/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyById(int id) // your id type
        => new JsonResult(await _mediator.Send(id));
```

But this is bad practice.
The most suitable would be just **host/company/id
by the get 1 company.**

Comment: Now it finds the method but it throws an exception probably because the mediator expects as parameter a query/command, not an integer.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem by doing the following thing ,[HttpGet("getCompanyById/{Id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanyById(int id, [FromQuery] GetCompanyById.Query query)
        {
            query.Id = id;

            return new JsonResult(await _mediator.Send(query));
        }